# Missing symbol compile error in C. Basic header file setup

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header, symbols

I'm working on a C project implementing some generic containers and am having this weird issue when compiling. Here is some sample code that also replicates the error.

foo.h

```
void fooprint(void);
```

foo.c

```
 #include "foo.h"
 #include <stdio>
 void fooprint(void){
    printf("bar");
    return;
 }
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void){
    fooprint();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile by typing

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

and this is what terminal outputs

```
Undefined symbols:
"_fooprint", referenced from:
  _main in ccfMXGzj.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling this on an OSX system but have also tried compiling on a red hat machine with the same effect.

The solution is probably painfully obvious but I have had multiple friends I'm working with look at this and they couldnt see the problem. I've googled around a lot but most symbol error issues are usually pertaining to objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile them together:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c foo.c
```

Or maybe make a Makefile ?

```
all: main

main: main.o foo.o

main.o: main.c

foo.o: foo.c
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile also `foo.c` into an object file and link all of them together:

```
gcc -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -o main.o main.c
gcc -o main main.o foo.o
```

Yes, this is simple, so I recommend you to read a good C book and step these easy steps.